# Qual a utilidade do operador til no CSS?

Tags: css, css-seletores

Ao ler alguns códigos vejo que é comum a utilização do til (`~`) na definição do seletor. Ex.:

```css
.effeckt-show.effeckt-modal-wrap ~ .effeckt-modal-overlay { ... }
```

Código retirado do [Effeckt.css](https://github.com/h5bp/Effeckt.css/blob/master/css/effeckt.css#L1520).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Existem 2 condições de uso do `~`

1. Selecionar todos os elementos com um atributo contendo determinado valor:

```css
[attribute~=value]
```

Por exemplo, `[title~=flower]`, para selecionar elementos com o atributo `title` contendo `flower`.

2. Selecionar todo elemento que é precedido por outro:

```css
element1~element2
```

Por exemplo, `p~ul` seleciona todo elemento `ul` que é precedido por um elemento `p`.

---

Na sua pergunta, é o segundo caso.
Ele está selecionando todo elemento `.effeckt-modal-overlay` que é precedido pelo elemento `.effeckt-show.effeckt-modal-wrap`

Fonte: [W3Schools CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 11):

Seria o "irmão geral".

É parecido com o operador de irmão adjacente (`+`), diferindo no ponto de que o elemento sendo selecionado não precisa suceder imediatamente o primeiro, mas em qualquer lugar depois.

Por exemplo:

```css
.first {
  color: green;
}

div.first+div {
  color: pink;
}

div.first~p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">First</div>
<div>Com estilo - Selecionado pelo "+"</div>
<div>Div sem estilo</div>
<p> Com estilo, selecionado pelo "~" </p>
```

Comment: +1 pelo exemplo no JSFiddle **e** por ter posto o código pertinente aqui.

Answer (score 7):

Segundo o [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), pela [tradução do Maujor](https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/seletores-css3.php):

> 14.4. Elemento de combinação irmão em geral
>
> O elemento de combinação irmão em geral consiste de dois seletores simples separados por um sinal de "til" (`~`). Este seletor casa ocorrências do segundo elemento seletor simples que sejam precedidos pelo primeiro elemento seletor simples. Ambos os elementos devem ter o mesmo elemento pai, mas o segundo elemento não precisa seguir-se imediatamente após o primeiro.
>
> Exemplo:
>
> ```css
> h1 ~ pre
> ```
>
> representa um elemento `pre` seguindo um elemento `h1`. Essa é uma descrição correta e válida, mas parcial, de:
>
> ```html
> <h1>Definition of the function a</h1>
> <p>Function a(x) has to be applied to all figures in the table.</p>
> <pre>function a(x) = 12x/13.5</pre>
> ```

Quando os dois seletores estão sob o mesmo elemento pai, o estilo em questão se aplica a ambos, mesmo que haja elementos no meio.

Comment: Se puder traduzir a definição ganha meu +1. O Maujor tinha traduzido tudo pelo que me lembro. Vale a pena pegar dele pra não errar na tradução sem querer

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz opa, dá uma olhada. Acho que era dessa tradução que vc estava falando.