# Como funcionam os seletores >, + , ~ no CSS?

Tags: css, css-seletores

## Seletor `+`

> Pega o primeiro elemento encontrado após sua declaração.

```css
div + p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
<p>Este é um paragrafo</p>
<p>Este é outro paragrafo</p>
```

## Seletor `~`

> Adiciona estilo a todos os elementos encontrados após a sua declaração, e não são descentes de de outro elemento(filhos).

```css
div ~ p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
<p>Este é um paragrafo</p>
<p>Este é outro paragrafo</p>
<div>
  <p>Este é outro paragrafo</p>
</div>
```

## Seletor `>`

> Todos os elementos que sejam filhos de outro elemento.

```css
div > p {
   font-size: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Este é um paragrafo</p>
  <p>Este é outro paragrafo</p>
 </div>
<p>Este é outro paragrafo</p>
```

## Minhas dúvidas:

- Meu entendimento está nas citações, estou falando alguma bobagem?
- O que ainda dá pra extrair desses seletores?
- Existe diferença de usar `div p {}` em vez de `div > p`?

***Obs:*** Se tiver algo a implementar ficaria muito grato.

Comment: Só pra constar, isto **não é CSS3** ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento jurava que sim, edito a pergunta?

Comment: Sim, isso existe desde o CSS2.1 (talvez o 2.0)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendi, bom ter editado. Vlw demais

Comment: **Relacionados:** [O que significa o sinal de + no CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91175/3635) - [Qual a utilidade do operador til no CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6745/3635) - [Qual a diferença entre os seletores “element element” e “element>element”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2256/3635)

Comment: **Relacionado também:** [O que significa sinal de >, :: , +, e & em css?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252589/8063)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Existe diferença de usar `div p` em vez de `div > p`?

Sim, existe. O seletor `div p` atinge todos os elementos `p` que se encontram dentro de um elemento `div`, mas isso não se aplica apenas a filhos diretos. Qualquer elemento `p` que estiver dentro de `div` será atingido. Por sua vez, o seletor `div > p` apenas atinge os elementos `p` que possuem como elemento pai um elemento `div`.

Veja o exemplo abaixo. Ao fazer `div p { color: red; }` estou dizendo que todos os elementos `p` dentro de um `div` devem possuir a cor de fonte vermelha. Porém, fazendo `div > p { color: green; }` eu digo que aqueles que possuírem como elemento pai o `div` devem possuir a cor de fonte verde. Desta forma, o primeiro parágrafo ficará com a cor de fonte verde, enquanto o segundo ficará com a cor de fonte vermelha.

```css
div p { color: red; }
div > p { color: green; }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Primeiro parágrafo</p>
  <footer>
    <p>Segundo parágrafo</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Podemos definir, então:

- `div p` atinge todos os elementos `p` DENTRO de um `div`;
- `div > p` atinge todos os elementos `p` cujo ELEMENTO PAI é um `div`.

> O que ainda dá pra extrair desses seletores?

O seletor `div + p`, por sua vez, atingirá todos os elementos `p` que são definidos IMEDIATAMENTE após um elemento `div`. Ao utilizá-lo com elementos `li`, por exemplo, atingirá todos os elementos, exceto o primeiro. Muito útil para definir uma borda interna que separa os elementos.

```css
li + li { border-top: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

O seletor `div ~ p`, por sua vez, atinge todos os elementos `p` que são precedidos por um elemento `div`, mas não necessariamente de forma imediata. Ou seja, ambos os elementos devem possuir o mesmo elemento pai, mas o elemento `p` não precisa suceder `div` imediatamente.

> Perceba que o seletor `div + p`, embora atinja o elemento `p` que é definido imediatamente após `div`, irá atingir TODOS os elementos `p` que satisfazerem esta condição. Perceba no exemplo abaixo onde existem dois elementos `h2` que são definidos imediatamente após `h1` e ambos são estilizados com a cor verde.

```css
h1 ~ h2 { color: red; background: cyan; }
h1 + h2 { color: green; }
```

```html
<h1>Título 1.1<h1>
<h2>Título 2.1</h2>

<p>Qualquer texto aqui...</p>

<h2>Título 2.2</h2>

<h1>Título 1.2<h1>
<h2>Título 2.1</h2>

<p>Qualquer texto aqui...</p>

<h2>Título 2.2</h2>
```

Podemos, então, definir:

- O seletor `div + p` atinge todos os elementos `p` que sucedem IMEDIATAMENTE um elemento `div`;
- Enquanto o seletor `div ~ p` atinge todos os elementos `p` que são PRECEDIDOS, não necessariamente de forma imediata, por um elemento `div`;

> Meu entendimento está nas partes amarelas, estou falando alguma bobagem?

De forma simplificada, estão corretas. Só alguns termos que poderiam ser ajustados para definir exatamente o contexto.

- `div p`: todos os elementos `p` DENTRO de um elemento `div`;
- `div > p`: todos os elementos `p` que são FILHOS DIRETOS de um elemento `div`;
- `div + p`: todos os elementos `p` que são posicionados IMEDIATAMENTE após um elemento `div`;
- `div ~ p`: todos os elementos `p` que são PRECEDIDOS por um elemento `div`, dentro de um mesmo elemento pai;

Comment: Essa parte `div + p: todos os elementos p que são posicionados IMEDIATAMENTE após um elemento div;` fiquei com uma dúvida. Meu exemplo só pega o primeiro `p` encontrado. E pelo que entendi você disse que pega todos, é isso mesmo @Anderson? No mais ficou bem claro, gostei demais dos exemplos :)

Comment: @Marconi, são todos do DOM, no caso. Se houverem mais de um `p` que sucedem `div`, todos serão estilizados. Atinge apenas o primeiro para aquela determinada `div`, mas se houverem outras, também serão atingidas. Alterei o exemplo deste seletor e adicionei uma nota esclarecendo.

Comment: Deixei um [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4f57oqq/) explicando o que explicou por último.