# Pegar o elemento filho do filho no css

Tags: css, css3

Tenho a seguinte estrutura html:

```
<div class="box1">
 <p>texto</p>
 <p>texto</p>
 <p><img src="imagem1.jpg"></p>
 <p>texto</p>
</div>
<div class="box2">
 <p>texto</p>
 <p>texto</p>
 <p><img src="imagem1.jpg"></p>
 <p>texto</p>
</div>
```

Como eu faço para aplicar, por exemplo, um padding na tag img dentro do box2 via css?

Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Pelo título da pergunta, acredito que a solução seria:

```
div > p > img {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

O operador `>` irá buscar qualquer elemento filho direto entre os elementos relacionados. Isto é, `div > p` buscará todos os elementos `p` que possuem um elemento pai `div` e `p > img` buscará todos os elementos `img` que possuem um elemento pai `p`.

Veja um exemplo:

```css
div > p > img {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
 <p>texto</p>
 <p>texto</p>
 <p><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></p>
 <p>texto</p>
</div>
<div class="box2">
 <p>texto</p>
 <p>texto</p>
 <p><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></p>
 <p>texto</p>
</div>
```

[Como funcionam os seletores >, + , ~ no CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194920/5878)

Answer (score 1):

usa assim:

```
.box2 p img
{
   Código
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.box2 img {
   padding: 5px;
}
```

Como vc só tem uma imagem dentro do box2 vc pode fazer como exemplificado acima (com herança).