# Quando coloco input dentro de alguma div o javascript não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Eu quero aplicar o css em um formulario mas quando vou colocar os inputs dentro de alguma div o javascript não funciona Veja o código:
No caso quando digito o email e a senha era para o botão ficar azul ativado.

```
<style>
    .btnDisabled{
        pointer-events:none;
        outline:none;
        border: none;
        background: gray; 
    }
    .btnEnabled{
        outline:none;
        border: none;
        background: blue; color: white;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">< /script>

<form id="formLog" method="post" action="website/login">
    <input type="text" id="txtELog" name="txtELog" placeholder="Userlogin ou E-mail: *" />
    <input type="password" id="txtPassLog" name="txtPassLog" placeholder="Senha: *" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnLog" name="btnLog" value="Login" disabled="disabled" class="btnDisabled" />
</form>

<script>
  $ (' #formLog > input').on('input', function () {
    var emptyLog = false;
    $('form > input, form > select').each(function () {
        if ($('#txtELog').val() == '' || $('#txtPassLog').val() == '') {
            emptyLog = true;
        }
    });
    if (emptyLog) {
        $('#btnLog').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#btnLog').attr('class', 'btnDisabled');
    } else {
        $('#btnLog').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#btnLog').attr('class', 'btnEnabled');
    }
});

</script>
```

Eu quero fazer isso no formulário:

```
<form id="formLog" method="post" action="website/login">
    <div class="inputText">< input type="text" id="txtELog" name="txtELog" placeholder="Userlogin ou E-mail: *" /></div>
    <div class="inputText">< input type="password" id="txtPassLog" name="txtPassLog" placeholder="Senha: *" /></div>
    <div class="inputButton">< input type="submit" id="btnLog" name="btnLog" value="Login" disabled="disabled" class="btnDisabled" /></div>
</form>
```

Mas quando faço isso e preencho os dois campos o javascript de ativar o botão não funciona. Alguém pode me ajudar? Preciso colocar esses inputs dentro de suas respectivas divs pra estilizar o formulário.

Comment: Você que escreveu esse código? Sabe o que significa o seletor `#formLog > input` que utilizou no jQuery? Talvez valha a leitura de [Como funcionam os seletores >, + , ~ no CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194920/5878)

Answer (score 5):

Tem que retirar do seletor o sinal `>`. Quando você coloca as `div`s, os `inputs` deixam de ser descendentes diretos do seletor `#formLog` indicados pelo sinal `>`:

```js
$(' #formLog  input').on('input', function () {
 var emptyLog = false;
 $('form input, form select').each(function () {
     if ($('#txtELog').val() == '' || $('#txtPassLog').val() == '') {
         emptyLog = true;
     }
 });
 if (emptyLog) {
  $('#btnLog').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#btnLog').attr('class', 'btnDisabled');
 } else {
  $('#btnLog').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#btnLog').attr('class', 'btnEnabled');
 }
});
```

```css
.btnDisabled{
    pointer-events:none;
    outline:none;
    border: none;
    background: gray; 
}
.btnEnabled{
    outline:none;
    border: none;
    background: blue; color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formLog" method="post" action="website/login">
<div class="inputText"><input type="text" id="txtELog" name="txtELog" placeholder="Userlogin ou E-mail: *" /></div>
<div class="inputText"><input type="password" id="txtPassLog" name="txtPassLog" placeholder="Senha: *" /></div>
<div class="inputButton"><input type="submit" id="btnLog" name="btnLog" value="Login" disabled="disabled" class="btnDisabled" /></div>
</form>
```

Caso contrário, teria que fazer assim: `$('#formLog > div > input')` se quisesse se referir apenas aos `input`s descendentes diretos de `div`s dentro do `#formlog`.

**O que é um descendente direto?**

É um elemento-filho do primeiro nível da *árvore*:

```
<div>
   <span> <-- descendente direto da div
      <p></p> <-- descendente direto do span
      <a></a> <-- descendente direto do span
   </span>
   <h1></h1> <-- descendente direto da div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Duas coisas que pude observar:**

- Os inputs estão com espaço entre a tag de abertura "< input". Deve regirar esse espaço.
- Já que você quer colocar o efeito para qualquer input dentro do form em questão, deve retirar o sinal ">" e deixar somente "#formLog  input", assim qualquer input dentro de #formLog pegará o efeito.