# Trabalhar com <tr><td> para otimizar JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Quero estudar mais sobre as `<table>` `<tr>` `<td>` etc, para otimizar meus projetos.
Exemplo: Tenho 4 `<tr>` com 2 `<td>` cada, ao aplicar uma formula em jQuery por exemplo, que some o primeiro `<td>` com o segundo `<td>` de cada `<tr>` utilizando pouca formula. Quero saber como referenciar o primeiro com o segundo de cada linha.
Alguma idéia?

Comment: A forma mais apropriada de fazer depende do objetivo, assim como da estrutura html que está a utilizar. Tente ser mais especifico nesses dois pontos

Comment: Meu único objetivo é estudar a estrutura, porem não sei por o que procurar no google para esse estudo.

Comment: Não ficou muito claro. Vc quer que suma os dois tds de cada linha?

Comment: Se cada linha tem 2 td, vai sumir a table toda.

Comment: Subscrevo o que o @DvD disse, não ficou de fato claro. O que quis dizer com esta ultima afirmação "Quero saber como referenciar o primeiro com o segundo de cada linha" ?

Comment: Não consegui ser claro na pergunta, desculpe-me, o objetivo é estudar o referenciamento da estrutura.. para otimizar os projetos em jQuery, a soma é só um exemplo para o caso de eu ter 150 <tr> e 20 <td> em cada <tr>, ai imagina o tamanho do jQuery se for fazer soma por soma em cada <tr>, entende?

Comment: a ideia é por assim.. jQuery -> some a primeira <td> com a segunda <td> de cada <tr> e retorne o resultado no terceiro <td> de cada <tr> ===>> lembrando, esse é somente um exemplo

Comment: Vc diz somar valores numéricos de uma td a outra?

Comment: o objetivo acho que ficou claro, somente o estudo da estrutura, como navegar pelas tables do html e fazer os referenciamentos pelos <tr> e <td>... nao encontro nada disso no google

Comment: nao DvD, quero saber como fazer o jQuery entender o que é a primeira <td> de cada <tr>.. a soma é só um exemplo para tentar deixar a pergunta mais clara (sem sucesso) kk...

Comment: O primeiro `<td>` de cada `<tr>` é dado por `$("tr").children().first()`. É isso que queria saber? Ou até mesmo tudo no seletor, com `$("tr td:first-child")`. Neste ultimo caso é puramente CSS o Jquery nem é relevante

Comment: isso!, é essa a ideia, tem alguma documentação, ou algum nome especifico para que eu possa me aprofundar nesse referenciamento??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para referenciar a primeira `td` de cada `tr`, você pode usar duas maneiras:

**1ª: com `first-child`:**

```
$("tbody tr td:first-child").css("color","red");
```

> `:first-child` é uma [pseudo-classe](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) que, neste caso, referencia
>   toda primeira `td` filha de uma `tr` na `tbody`.

**2ª: com `nth-child(1)`:**

```
$("tbody tr td:nth-child(1)").css("color","red");
```

Para referenciar a segunda `td` de cada `tr`, você pode usar `nth-child(2)`:

```
$("tbody tr td:nth-child(2)").css("color","red");
```

Para referenciar a terceira `td` em diante, basta trocar o index para 3, 4 em diante:

```
$("tbody tr td:nth-child(index)").css("color","red");
```

> Lembrado que o index de `nth-child()` no jQuery começa com 1.

Comment: isso mesmo!! existe algum nome para eu poder me aprofundar, estudar esses referenciamentos? Para eu saber se ele só funciona com <tr>, ou se funciona com <div> também..

Comment: @ThiagoKoller Sim. Estude pseudo-classes e pseudo-elementos e também seletores CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes e http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/guia-completo-seletores-css3.php

Comment: @ThiagoKoller Interessante também esta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/250488/8063

Comment: @ThiagoKoller Funciona com qualquer elemento.