# Scroll infinito em one page com dados estaticos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte extrutura e quero limitar a quantidade de "class/postagens" a serem exibidas. Quero criar um botão para que, ao clicar, ele exiba e vá mostrando mais e mais "class/postagens". Eu só encontrei tutoriais que explicam como fazer isso buscando os dados no mysql e o que eu preciso não necessita de nenhum dado do banco pois eu já possuo o conteúdo na própria página one page. O código é esse:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Carregamento</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="posts">

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem 2</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem 3</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem 4</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem 5</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem 6</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem 7</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Eu quero limitar as postagens em apenas duas e a medida que eu clique em um botão de "ver mais", ai vai acrescentando mais dados na visualização.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como vc falou que o site era estático é possível fazer apenas com CSS com poucas linhas inclusive. O mais importante aqui é "concatenar" direitinho o HTML. Nesse modelo não precisa de jQuery ou JS

A ideia é que sempre que o `input` for *checado* ele mostra o próximo bloco, esse bloco por sua vez tem dentro mais um `input` que quando *checado* mostra o próximo bloco. Cada bloco novo bloco sempre vai ficando dentro do bloco anterior. Repare na indentação do código ok.

Veja o exemplo, `repare que o CSS nunca muda, independente da quantidade do conteúdo`, ***vc só precisa no HTML ir colocando os bloco um dentro do outro.*** Nãi importa a quantidade de divs que vai ter dentro de cada bloco, isso facilita para vc mostra de 2 em 2 como no exemplo ou de 1 em 1 ou 4 em 4, isso não importa pra regra CSS. Veja os comentários que deixei no HTML.

```css
.show,
input,
input:checked + label {
  display: none;
}
input:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
}

label {
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <div>item 01</div>
    <div>item 02</div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="b1">
    <label for="b1">btn</label>
    <div class="show">
      <div>item 03</div>
      <div>item 04</div>

      <input type="checkbox" id="b2">
      <label for="b2">btn</label>
      <div class="show">
        <div>item 05</div>
        <div>item 06</div>

        <input type="checkbox" id="b3">
        <label for="b3">btn</label>
        <div class="show">
          <div>item 07</div>
          <div>item 08</div>

          <!-- esse é um ex de bloco completo -->
          <input type="checkbox" id="b4">
          <label for="b4">btn</label>
          <div class="show">
            <div>item 09</div>
            <!-- vc pode colocar quantas divs quiser aqui -->
            <!-- aqui deve vir o próximo bloco completo ex: 11 e 12 -->
          </div>
          <!-- fim do bloco completo -->

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Fantástico, obrigado, eu não sabia que dava pra fazer utilizando apenas css. Aproveitando seu comentário, vc utiliza + e também utiliza ~, eu costumo usar ambos avulsos, existe uma diferença entre eles? me parece fazer a mesma coisa

Comment: @OtavioFagundes na verdade o seletor + faz referencia ao elemento irmão ex: div + div {} significa que o css só vai afetar a div que é seguida de outra, se no seu html estive div section div o css não funciona, já com o seletor ~ vc pega todas as divs irmãs independente se tem outras tag entre elas, e não só a primeira tag irma entende. Da uma olhada nessa pergunta que vai te esclarecer mais https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6745/qual-a-utilidade-do-operador-til-no-css E particularmente nesse exemplo eu usei ~ pq entre o checkbox e a div tem uma label que eu queria ignorar e o + não daria

Comment: Obrigado pelas explicações

Answer (score 5):

Usando o seletor **[:lt(-index)](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)** do jQuery você consegue ir mostrando os elementos de acordo com o valor especificado.

Supondo que você queira mostrar de 2 em 2 itens, primeiro você deve esconder todos os elementos menos os 2 primeiros. Para isso deve colocar no CSS o seletor `:nth-child` com uma fórmula:

```
.postagens:nth-child(n+3){ /* esconde todos menos os 2 primeiros */
   display: none;
}
```

Crie um botão que irá mostrar os demais elementos após o último elemento, e crie um evento `click` para esse botão que irá executar a função que irá exibir os elementos.

Outras explicações no código:

```js
$(function(){
   // captura o click no button filho da classe .posts
   $(".posts > button").click(function(){
      var mostrar = 2; // quantos irá mostrar a cada clique
      var invs = $(".postagens:not(:visible)").length; // conta quantos estão invisíveis
      // se o número de invisíveis for menor ou igual ao número de mostrar
      // mostrar o restante e esconder o botão
      if(invs <= mostrar){
         $(".postagens").show();
         $(this).hide();
      }else{
         // o seletor ":lt" com valor negativo ignora o número especificado de elementos
         // a partir do último elemento da lista
         $(".postagens:lt(-"+(invs-mostrar)+")").show();
      }
   });
});
```

```css
.postagens:nth-child(n+3){ /* esconde todos menos os 2 primeiros */
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="posts">

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem 2</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem 3</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem 4</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem 5</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem 6</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

    <div class="postagens">
      <h1>titulo postagem 7</h1>
      <p>conteúdo postagem</p>
    </div>

   <button>Mais..</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Cara não conhecia esse seletor do jQuery, top.

Comment: Muito útil em alguns casos :)